# How to get the default ResourceBundle regardless of current default Locale

Tags: java, internationalization, locale, resourcebundle

I have three resource files in class path:

labels.properties:

```
language = Default
```

labels_en.properties:

```
language = English
```

labels_fr.properties:

```
language = French
```

Is there a way to get a `ResourceBundle` object that always loads `labels.properties` NO MATTER what my default `Locale` is?

`ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels")` returns the one corresponding to the current default locale (as expected).

The only way I can find is to set the default locale to a non-existing locale, but this may break other modules.

Thank you!

```
Locale.setDefault( Locale.ENGLISH);
Assert.assertEquals( "English", ResourceBundle.getBundle( "labels").getString( "language"));
Locale.setDefault( Locale.FRENCH);
Assert.assertEquals( "French", ResourceBundle.getBundle( "labels").getString( "language"));
Assert.assertEquals( "French", ResourceBundle.getBundle( "labels", new Locale( "do-not-exist")).getString( "language"));
Locale.setDefault( new Locale( "do-not-exist"));
Assert.assertEquals( "Default", ResourceBundle.getBundle( "labels").getString( "language"));
```

Comment: You might need to call `ResourceBundle.clearCache()` before trying: `ResourceBundle.getBundle( "labels", new Locale( "do-not-exist")).getString( "language"));`. (From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981521/dynamically-change-resourcebundle-locale-in-java?rq=1)).

Comment: @Duncan Thank you for your comment. It didn't work, though. If `new Locale("do-not-exist")` (I should have named it "does-not-exist"...) is not found, `ResourceBundle` tries to load one with `Locale.getDefault()` instead, not the default version of the bundle.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass in a [ResourceBundle.Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) which, regardless of requested Locale, always searches only the root ResourceBundle:

```
ResourceBundle rootOnly = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels",
    new ResourceBundle.Control() {
        @Override
        public List<Locale> getCandidateLocales(String name,
                                                Locale locale) {
            return Collections.singletonList(Locale.ROOT);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I didn't know the existence of `Locale.ROOT`, I thought `new Locale("")` were not allowed... By the way, isn't your code equivalent to `ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels", Locale.ROOT)`? Are there other reasons to extends `Control` (for this specific problem)? Following test case passes: `Locale.setDefault( Locale.ENGLISH); Assert.assertEquals( "Default", ResourceBundle.getBundle( "labels", Locale.ROOT).getString( "language"));`

Comment: 1. Yes, passing Locale.ROOT to every call to ResourceBundle.getBundle will accomplish the same thing.  2. There are many other reasons to use ResourceBundle.Control, such as controlling the caching of bundles and controlling whether to only search for .properties resources and/or subclasses of ResourceBundle.  The javadoc (to which I linked) lists all the behaviors you can override.

Comment: Agree with @VGR, if you go through the `java.util.ResourceBundle` class, invoke `ResourceBundle.getBundle("baseName", Locale.ROOT);`  will do the same thing but skip the step to try to get bundle with `Locale.getDefault()`, which is redundant in this case.